# How does one add commands to nrpe.cfg for Percona MySQL plugins on NRPE client?

Tags: mysql, nagios, percona, nrpe

How do you add commands to `nrpe.cfg` for Percona MySQL plugins on NRPE client?

```
To configure percona-nrpe plugins for mysql you will have to do 3 things viz : 
1. define commands in command.cfg
2. Define service in service.cfg
3. Add commands on client to nrpe.cfg
```

First 2 can be easily done for help http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/install-percona-monitoring-tools-for-nagios-mysql-plugins#comment-43181

I found less help available for 3rd point ie how to add commands in nrpe.cfg on client side.  So can someone tell me how to add commands on client side in nrpe.cfg ?

Comment: For sample command.cfg & service.cfg ref http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/install-percona-monitoring-tools-for-nagios-mysql-plugins#comment-43181

Comment: Is there any way to come out of off topic for this question ??

Comment: what can I do here to come out of ban ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure percona-nrpe plugins for mysql you will have to do 3 things viz :
1. define commands 
2. Define service
3. Add commands on client to nrpe.cfg

First 2 can be easily done for help refer http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/install-percona-monitoring-tools-for-nagios-mysql-plugins#comment-43181

I found less help available for 3rd point ie to add commands in nrpe.cfg on client side so here is sample nrpe.cfg for percona-mysql plugins !

```
command[check_mysql_service]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mysqld.pl -H 192.168.1.68 -u root -p xx -a slow_queries -w 44 -c 55 

command[check_mysql_innodb]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/pmp-check-mysql-innodb -H 192.168.1.68 -C idle_blocker_duration -w 60 -c 600

command[check_mysql_innodb]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/pmp-check-mysql-innodb -H 192.168.1.68 -C max_duration -w 86400 -c 172800

command[check_mysql_active_threads]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-status -H 192.168.1.68 -x Threads_running -w 20 -c 40

command[rdba_mysql_pidfile]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-pidfile

command[rdba_unix_memory]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-unix-memory -d -w 96 -c 98

command[check_mysql_deadlocks]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-deadlocks -H 192.168.1.68 -i 5 -w 12 -c 60

command[check_mysql_connections]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-status -H 192.168.1.68 -x Threads_connected -o / -y max_connections -T pct -w 80 -c 95

command[check_mysql_replication_delay]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pmp-check-mysql-replication-delay -H 192.168.1.68 -w 650 -c 600

command[check_mysql_processlist]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/pmp-check-mysql-processlist -H 192.168.1.68 -w 80 -c 100

command[check_mysql_replication_running]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/pmp-check-mysql-replication-running -H 192.168.1.68
```

Comment: Answers should include details. Code fragments without details and explanations are useless.